# How do I plot a a grouping of 3 variables?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I would like to plot the monthly quantity sold per client over a year. After a groupby of three variables `df.groupby(['Year', 'Week', 'Client'])[Quantity].sum()`, I am left with a column like this:

```
                       Quantity
Year    Week    Client  
2012     1       Coke      200
                 Pepsi     100
                 7UP       400
         2       Coke      500
                 Pepsi     750
                 7UP       200
         3       Coke      120
                 Pepsi     100
                 7UP       050
... ... ... ...
2020    22       Coke      100 
             Mountain Dew  650
                Fanta      110
        23       7UP       100 
                 Pepsi     199
                 Coke      200
... ... ... ...
```

I want to only show weekly quantities for all Clients in the last 10 weeks of 2020 (i.e. week 15-week 25) out of this entire dataframe.

How would I go on about selecting this data and then plotting a bar plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df_groups = df.groupby(['Year', 'Week', 'Client'])['Quantity'].sum()

# slicing the selected weeks
df_plot = df_groups.loc[2020].loc[15:25]

df_plot.unstack('Client').plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]